# The NuGet Installer task used in TFS 2017 build definition fails to clear the global-packages folder with an error

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

We have a build definition in place created in TFS 2017, which builds a .net solution that has dependency on some of our NuGet packages, during compilation the solution restores the NuGet package from packages (global-packages) folder present at this path `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages` instead of downloading latest one from  our internal feed.

I saw a command at this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore) to avoid using the global-packages folder, but when I added the `nuget locals global-packages -clear` argument in NuGet installer task, which is used to restore the nuget packages, the task failed with the below error saying `unknown option -Clear`.

The NuGet Version I am using is 3.5.0 in the task.

```
2019-09-05T09:27:18.8819742Z ##[section]Starting: NuGet restore $(build.sourcesdirectory)/IntelliSuiteService.sln
2019-09-05T09:27:18.8819742Z ==============================================================================
2019-09-05T09:27:18.8819742Z Task         : NuGet Installer
2019-09-05T09:27:18.8819742Z Description  : Installs or restores missing NuGet packages
2019-09-05T09:27:18.8819742Z Version      : 0.2.31
2019-09-05T09:27:18.8819742Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2019-09-05T09:27:18.8819742Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613747)
2019-09-05T09:27:18.8819742Z ==============================================================================
2019-09-05T09:27:19.4601187Z [command]C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
2019-09-05T09:27:19.4757465Z Active code page: 65001
2019-09-05T09:27:19.5069958Z Detected NuGet version 3.5.0.1938 / 3.5.0
2019-09-05T09:27:19.5226206Z SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
2019-09-05T09:27:19.5226206Z [command]F:\Builds\NextGen_Gated\_tasks\NuGetInstaller_333b11bd-d341-40d9-afcf-b32d5ce6f23b\0.2.31\node_modules\nuget-task-common\NuGet\3.5.0\NuGet.exe restore -NonInteractive F:\Builds\NextGen_Gated\2\s\SuiteService.sln -NoCache nuget locals global-packages -Clear
2019-09-05T09:27:20.1007732Z Unknown option: '-Clear'
2019-09-05T09:27:20.1163983Z ##[error]Error: F:\Builds\NextGen_Gated\_tasks\NuGetInstaller_333b11bd-d341-40d9-afcf-b32d5ce6f23b\0.2.31\node_modules\nuget-task-common\NuGet\3.5.0\NuGet.exe failed with return code: 1
2019-09-05T09:27:20.1163983Z ##[error]Packages failed to install
2019-09-05T09:27:20.1320334Z ##[section]Finishing: NuGet restore $(build.sourcesdirectory)/SuiteService.sln
```

Comment: You need to run it in separately, not with the nuget restore command.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk separately but with which task? any batch task would work?

Comment: Yes :) or just log in to your agent machine and run it once on the command line.

Comment: Its giving me Unknown command: 'nuget' error, when i provided it the follwoing command in cmd "F:\srp\NuGet\3.5.0\NuGet.exe nuget locals global-packages -clear"

Comment: Try without `nuget` (because you already give the exe path)

Comment: Thanks, It worked but had to add a new batch task in all the Build definition to clear the global package folder.

Comment: Did you try to run it on the machine and then run the build (without a new batch task)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run the command separately from the `nuget restore` command.

You can can log in to the agent machine and run it from the command line, or in the build add a command line or batch task that run the command.